# how to associate single entity to multiple entities(pojo classes)

Tags: hibernate, jpa

does anyone here knows the correct way of associating a single entity(a pojo class) to multiple classes.. im currently working on a situation where `mainClass` has a one-to-many relationship to `subClass` and `subClass` has one-to-many relationship to `unitsClass` too. the relationship of these classes looks like this:

- mainClass - oneToMany - subClass
- subClass - manyToOne - mainClass AND oneToMany - unitsClass
- unitsClass - manyToOne - subClass

i dont know if its possible for `subClass` to contain multiple associations to multiple classes.if not, what would be the best way to address this problem? im using hibernate annotations.

hope someone could help me out on this.

thank you so much!

Comment: The answer to the question in your title is "Yes".  That's not useful.  That cannot possibly be what you want to know.  Please fix your title to say the thing you want to know.  It sounds like you want to know which Hibernate annotations to use.  Please fix the title to actually say what you need.

Comment: btw, are you using JPA, or hibernate-only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In the simplest form it would look like this:

```
@Entity
public class MainClass {
   @OneToMany
   private List<SubClass> subclasses;

   // Id and other fields
}

@Entity
public clsas SubClass {
    @ManyToOne
    private MainClass mainClass 

    @OneToMany
    private List<UnitClass> unitClasses;
}

@Entity
public class UnitClass {
    @ManyToOne
    private SubClass subClass;
}
```

Comment: thanks. i've constructed the 3 classes this way and it works fine for the main class and subClass but i always get a NUllPointerException for the unitClass.

Comment: thanks! finally, i figured out the reason why NullPointerException occurs. thanks for you help again:P